# Create a new file with a Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am working on a visual studio code extension hat creates a new file in the current directory of the project. I am working on a VM.

Digging around I found the code below.

> const folderPath =
>   vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.toString().split(":")[1];

I receive the error message "no such file or directory, open 'C:\c%3A\Users\username\Desktop\Test\test.txt'

Is the c%3A because I am working on a VM?
Is there another way to pull the current directory of the project?

Comment: `c%3A` is URI-encoded `c:`. How that happened, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get around the error by changing my split to const folderPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.toString().split("c%3A")[1];

Comment: what do you do when the workspace is at drive D?